# Office 365 SMTP

Tags: smtp, office365

I am configuring an application to send emails from our Office 365 server.
 
Makes shipments to internal users of the organization, but not to external users

I have tried several configurations, I show you 2 examples:

myuser@mydomain.com have a Office 365 license

Example 1

```
#######################EXAMPLE_1#####################################
# Server configuration
ap.mail.config.host=mydomain-com.mail.protection.outlook.com
ap.mail.config.port=25
ap.mail.config.protocol=smtp
mail.protocol=smtp
mail.defaultEncoding = UTF-8
mail.smtp.auth=true
mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
mail.username =myuser@mydomain.com
mail.password =mypassword
mail.debug = false

# origen para los envios de correo
ap.mail.from=myuser@mydomain.com
ap.mail.from.name=XXXXXXXXXXXX
ap.timeOutSession=1800000 
###########################################################
```

With this configuration, It show this error:

```
nested exception is:
      com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 550 5.7.64 TenantAttribution; Relay Access Denied [VE1EUR01FT034.eop-EUR01.prod.protection.outlook.com]
```

Example2

```
######################EXAMPLE_2#################################
# MAIL SERVER
ap.mail.config.host=smtp.office365.com
ap.mail.config.port=587
ap.mail.config.protocol=smtp
mail.protocol=smtp
mail.defaultEncoding = UTF-8
mail.smtp.auth=true
mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
mail.username =myuser@mydomain.com
mail.password =mypassword
mail.debug = false

# origen para los envios de correo
ap.mail.from=myuser@mydomain.com
ap.mail.from.name=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
ap.timeOutSession=1800000

#############################################################
```

Whit this configuration, it show this error

```
 Failed message 1: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM [LO2P265CA0035.GBRP265.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]
```

Can someone help me?
  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Could you please send an email to an external user? The first example shows the error that you could refer to this link:

["550 5.7.64 TenantAttribution; Relay Access Denied SMTP" error when sending mail through Exchange Online Protection](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/3212877/550-5-7-64-tenantattribution-relay-access-denied-smtp-error-when-sendi)

The second example shows an error that the client is not authenticated, as described in the wrong message.

You need configure your Exchange SMTP to direct send. You could refer to the this link:

[Client was not authenticated to send anonymous email during MAIL FROM](https://support.solarwinds.com/Success_Center/Network_Performance_Monitor_(NPM)/Knowledgebase_Articles/Client_was_not_authenticated_to_send_anonymous_email_during_MAIL_FROM)